# How do I swap XML attributes in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a power shell script that is making a bunch of changes to an XML file, and it is all working except one part. I need to switch the values of two attributes for each occurrence in the XML file.  In the example below I need to swap the values for "Description" and "Name" for every Product.  How would I do this?

Existing XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MetrixXML xmlns="http://www.lithotechnics.com" SchemaVersion="1.0">
    <Project Description="" Name="test123" ProjectID="test123">
        <ProductPool>
            <Product Description="A #61792-39" Name="21170:01">
            </Product>
            <Product Description="B #61793-39" Name="21170:02">
            </Product>
            <Product Description="C #61728-39" Name="21170:03">
            </Product>
        </ProductPool>
    </Project>
</MetrixXML>
```

Should be converted to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MetrixXML xmlns="http://www.lithotechnics.com" SchemaVersion="1.0">
    <Project Description="" Name="test123" ProjectID="test123">
        <ProductPool>
            <Product Description="21170:01" Name="A #61792-39">
            </Product>
            <Product Description="21170:02" Name="B #61793-39">
            </Product>
            <Product Description="21170:03" Name="C #61728-39">
            </Product>
        </ProductPool>
    </Project>
</MetrixXML>
```

Comment: Same as with every other language. You get both values and [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_%28computer_science%29) them.

Comment: Thanks,  I guess I am wording my question poorly.  When I tried to swap the attributes, I was succeeding in swapping the first instance of the attribute values, but it then copied that same value for the first instance to every subsequent value for those attributes throughout the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to load your xml, iterate over the notes and swap the values:

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content 'Path_to_your_xml')
$xml.DocumentElement.Project.ProductPool.Product | % {
    $oldDescription = $_.Description
    $_.Description = $_.Name
    $_.Name = $oldDescription
}
$xml.Save('Path_to_your_xml')
```

Comment: Why not `$_.Description, $_.Name = $_.Name, $_.Description`?

Comment: @PetSerAl Nice hint, I didn't think about it.

Comment: @PetSerAl What is the advantage of this method?  It works, I just don't quite get what it is doing.

Comment: You can assign multiple variables with PowerShell. The advantage is that  you don't need to introduce a temp variable and its shorter. The downside: its maybe less readable. Just choose the one you like more.